# Как при помощи С++ получить список активных процессов Unix системы?

Tags: c++, linux, процесс

Нужно написать на чистом C++ код, который будет получать список активных и спящих процессов, погуглив ничего путного не нашёл. Спасибо

Comment: Что значит на "чистом С++"? Системный API всё равно придется использовать, т.к. в стандартной библиотеке нет функций для работы с процессами ОС.

Comment: мне прям интересно, какие же слова надо вбить в поисковик, чтобы не найти

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читайте то, что вам надо, из `/proc/`

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h> // for opendir(), readdir(), closedir()
#include <sys/stat.h> // for stat()

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>

#define PROC_DIRECTORY "/proc/"

int IsNumeric(const char* ccharptr_CharacterList)
{
    for ( ; *ccharptr_CharacterList; ccharptr_CharacterList++)
        if (*ccharptr_CharacterList < '0' || *ccharptr_CharacterList > '9')
            return 0; // false
    return 1; // true
}

int main()
{
    struct dirent* dirEntity = NULL ;
    DIR* dir_proc = NULL ;

    dir_proc = opendir(PROC_DIRECTORY) ;
    if (dir_proc == NULL)
    {
        perror("Couldn't open the " PROC_DIRECTORY " directory") ;
        return (pid_t) -2 ;
    }

    while ((dirEntity = readdir(dir_proc)) != 0) {
        if (dirEntity->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            if (IsNumeric(dirEntity->d_name)) {
                std::string path = std::string(PROC_DIRECTORY) + dirEntity->d_name + "/cmdline";

                std::ifstream cmdLineFile(path.c_str());
                std::string cmdLine;
                if (cmdLineFile) {

                    std::getline(cmdLineFile, cmdLine);

                }
                std:: cout << "pid: " << dirEntity->d_name << " " << cmdLine << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dir_proc) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

В linux, как и во многих других unix системах (во всех ли, не знаю) все процессы отражены в файловой системе procfs, которая смонтирована на точку /proc. Стандартные утилиты типа ps работают с ней.
Проще всего посмотреть исходники ps.
[procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/)

Если не надо знать о процессах особо много, то можно просто посмотреть, что есть /proc и выбрать те данные, которые нужны.

Описание файлового интерфейса procfs [Из документации на ядро](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)

Конкретно работает процесс или спит можно прочитать из `/proc/pid-процесса/stat`, там почти в самом начале буква 'S' или 'R' ... Та же информация в человеко-читаемом формате в `/proc/pid-процесса/status`